# joomla module navigation uing ajax

Tags: ajax, joomla

i am having a joomla module and i want to navigte from 1 page to another using ajax in the module how to do this?

Actually i want to create 3 combo boxes fetching data from database.One for country then on selecting country 2nd combobox will show states of the country then on selecting state the next combobox will show the city from the state therefore for applying the logic i have to specify the page where the logic reside but in joomla using ajax the request is not working.
What to do?

Comment: What do you mean by navigate from one page to another? can you explain further. Are you looking for pagination in your module using AJax

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to navigate from one independent page to another using Ajax in Joomla. In most cases it requires full page reload so Ajax is not really helpful here. As sushil bharwani mentioned, if you need to navigate through pagination pages, then here is some info: http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/forum/index.php?topic=8960.0

Comment: Actually the requirement of the question demands you to create new pages in the root folder from where the user can access pages so for navigating specify the urls in the root directory